# sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type?

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite

I am getting an error when trying to compile data from Python(3.9.1) to SQLite3.

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('newdB.db')

#Creates the table 'tbl_newdb' with an incrementing ID, and 'db_type' columns.
with conn:
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tbl_newdb( \
        ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, \
        db_type TEXT)")
    conn.commit()
conn.close()

conn = sqlite3.connect('newdB.db')

#Our list of data we will be grabbing from to fill the tables.
with conn:
    cur = conn.cursor()
    fileList = "information.docx","Hello.txt","myImage.png","myMovie.mpg","World.txt","data.pdf","myPhoto.jpg"
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO tbl_newdb (db_type) VALUES (?)",(fileList,))
    conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Here is the error message I am getting from the IDLE shell:

```
 line 22, in <module>
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO tbl_newdb (db_type) VALUES (?)",(str(fileList,)))
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 103 supplied.
```

Comment: The error message does not match your code. In the error message the `fileList` tuple is being converted to a string, but the posted code does not do that. Also the question title is different. You've got an answer from @pop, but try to keep things in sync when posting input, output and code in future questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TLDR: `execute` takes two arguments, a SQL query and a list of inputs with one element for each `(?)` arguments in your SQL.

What you want is `executemany` which accepts a list of a list of inputs. The solution looks like this:

```py
import sqlite3

# Create a database in memory for testing
conn = sqlite3.connect('newdB.db')

# Execute with the databse connection
with conn:
    cur = conn.cursor()

    # Create your table in the in-memory database
    cur.execute("""
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tbl_newdb(
        ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
        db_type TEXT
    )
    """)
    conn.commit()

# A list of parameters to pass to queries
# Notice we are making a list of lists
# `execute` takes a list of inputs for a single execution
parameterList = [
    ["information.docx"],
    ["Hello.txt"],
    ["myImage.png"],
    ["myMovie.mpg"],
    ["World.txt"],
    ["data.pdf"],
    ["myPhoto.jpg"],
]

with conn:
    # Execute the same query multiple times
    # Because we are passing one value to our sql, each list in parameterList
    # only has one element.
    cur.executemany(
        "INSERT INTO tbl_newdb(db_type) VALUES(?)",
        parameterList
    )
    conn.commit()

    # Print debugging information to prove we inserted things correctly
    cur.execute("SELECT db_type FROM tbl_newdb")
    print(cur.fetchall())

# Close the connection after creating the table
conn.close()
```

Note I have use `[...]` syntax instead of tuple `(...,)` syntax. Both are OK, I just prefer square braces for clarity, and because we have a lot of one-element lists.

You can also substitute `cur.exeutemany(...)` with a for loop like this:

A bit of explanation: `execute` takes two arguments, an SQL query and a list of parameters. You can think of the list of parameters as substitutions for every `(?)` in your SQL query. The first `(?)` is replaced with the first element in your parameter list, the second `(?)` with the second element in your list, and so on.

Let's figure out how we got here. When I first ran your code I got this output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "alt.py", line 20, in <module>
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO tbl_newdb (db_type) VALUES (?)",(fileList,))
sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.
```

`unsupported type` was a hint to me that you were putting `fileList` which is already a tuple, and wrapping it in another tuple. So I changed that `execute` line to:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO tbl_newdb (db_type) VALUES (?)", fileList)
```

Next we get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "alt.py", line 20, in <module>
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO tbl_newdb (db_type) VALUES (?)", fileList)
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 7 supplied.
```

That's weird. It's taking my list of 7 things and trying to stuff them into one binding? Interesting. What if we shorten `fileList` to just one element? Start small and see where we get. I change the line above the `execute` to

```
fileList = "information.docx"
```

and we get a similar but different error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "alt.py", line 20, in <module>
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO tbl_newdb (db_type) VALUES (?)", fileList)
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 16 supplied.
```

Hmm. 16 is the number of characters in `"information.docx"` so Python must be treating that string as a list of parameters. Let's wrap that in a list and see what happens:

```
fileList = ["information.docx"]
```

And with that we get our first success!

What happens if we add another element to the list?

```
fileList = ["information.docx", "other_file.txt"]
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "alt.py", line 20, in <module>
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO tbl_newdb (db_type) VALUES (?)", fileList)
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 2 supplied.
```

Science! It was successful with one element, but fails with two. This means that the second argument to `execute` needs to be a list with as many elements as `(?)` parameters in our SQL query.

Now we have a few options. We can either [read the SQLite Python docs and discover](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.executemany) `executemany`, or we can do a for loop:

```
for f in fileList:
    parameters = [f]
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO tbl_newdb (db_type) VALUES (?)", parameters)
conn.commit()
```

SQLite is very fast, so `executemany` and a for loop both yield similar performance.